# Server 2008 Web Edition IIS6 SMTP conflict

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-6, smtp, web

I'm using IIS6 Manager to setup the SMTP service on Windows Server 2008 Web Edition.

There seems to be a conflict (port 25?) which means that I cannot start and stop the Default SMTP server within IIS6. I can start and stop it with the services.msc snap in and this is reflected in state of the SMTP server in IIS6 manager.

I'm worried that none of the settings I want to get at within IIS6 (logging, authentication etc..) are having any effect. None of these settings are available within IIS7 in Web Edition.

Comment: IIS 6 on 2008 web edition? A case for RTFM - at least know what system you use, please. Server 2008 never had and never will ahve IIS 6.

Comment: @TomTom: AFAIK, the SMTP server provided with Windows Server 2008 *is* that of IIS6.

Comment: @TomTom, wrong, the SMTP service is still controlled via IIS6 manager

Comment: Yes, but IIS is not IIS 6. IIS 6 never is installed. The old SMTP service is a leftover - one best not installed, truthfully. I keep SMTP on a separate box for that reason.

Comment: @TomTom: SMTP Server feature in Windows Server 2008 requires IIS 6 Management Compatibility installed. SMTP still requires Metabase.xml due to some dependency when SMTP interacts along with other mail servers.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the port conflict issue, run `netstat -ano` and check which PID is using port 25. You can check the process using Task Manager by matching it with PID seen in netstat -ano. By default inetinfo.exe has control over port 25.

Answer (score 0):

HEy Vivek

Yes, your advice showed up a conflict with MESMTPC which is obviously the other SMTP server.

How many SMTP servers are there!!

Which is the best one to use or are they the same one with different management tools?

Comment: As many as you install. Seriously, there are quit a lot out there. In your case, for example: "mesmtpc.exe is a MESMTPC belonging to MailEnable from MailEnable Pty Ltd" - you (r someone else) already installed a third party SMTP Server.